# Integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\operatorname {d}\phi}{\sin\phi+4} $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$I have this integral which I consider as challenging.

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\d\phi}{\sin\phi+4} 
\end{equation}

I rewrite the denominator using  $\sin\phi=\frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i}$

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\d\phi}{\frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i}+4} 
\end{equation}

So, at this stage it is written with the form for complex numbers. But since I want to solve this using the Residue Theorem, how does one do that on this form?

Thanks

Comment: This integral is easy with the real substitution $t=\tan \phi/2$.

Comment: By the Residue theorem?

Comment: In mathjax you can use backslashes for almost everything; `\sin,\cos` renders properly. It is also more convenient to write `$$` instead of `\begin{equation}`

Comment: With regards to Rene's comment, look up "Weierstrass substitution"

Comment: You shouldn't need to access complex analysis to solve this problem

Comment: There is obviously a mistake in your calculations: $\frac{1}{\sin\phi +4} \ne -\frac{1}{8\sin\phi}$ since the LHS is continuous and the RHS isn't.

Comment: thanks for spotting this. corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi {d\phi\over {(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi})/2i}+4}$$
Now let $z=e^{i\phi}$ then the integral becomes $$\oint {dz\over iz[(z+1/z)/2i+4]}=\oint {dz\over z^2/2+4iz+1/2}$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: This is exactly what I though would be a tratable form for residue theorem.  Thanks. I need to factorize your denominator form. Then, the poles are considered on a half circle in the original problem. How do I form the new circle from this in z, or maybe this is not required, and I just form the residues for $z_1=i\sqrt{2}-i$ and $z_1=-i\sqrt{2}-i$

Comment: see update in the original post

Comment: Notice that the integral contour is enclosing $|z|\le1$ so the residue of $-i\sqrt2-i$ should not be calculated

Comment: Ah, thank you! That is noted.

Comment: PS Richard there may be an error in your reasoning,  sinx=$e^i\phi-e^-i\phi$. It appears you used plus instead of minus in the exponential relation of sine.

Comment: PS Richard there may be an error in your reasoning,  sinx=$1/2i/cdot(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi})$. It appears you used plus instead of minus in the exponential relation of sine. This changes the poles, and they become $\sqrt{3}-2$ and $-\sqrt{3}-2$. Both are outside of the unit circle.